# Can't resolve RSVP.Promise in QUnit integration test

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-testing

I am writing an integration test for my Ember.js application in QUnit. Before a test, I want to seed some test data by issuing HTTP requests to a dedicated testing API. I use `jQuery.post` to issue POST requests and I use `Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast` to turn the jQuery promise into an RSVP promise. However, it never seems to resolve. In the code below, it just hangs. The string `"STARTING"` is printed but neither `"DONE"` nor `"FAIL"` is printed.

I also tried creating a new RSVP Promise as described in the "Advanced usage" section of http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html, to no avail (it also hanged). If I don't wrap the jQuery promise into an  RSVP Promise, it does reach either the `"DONE"` or `"FAIL"`.

Why doesn't the RSVP Promise resolve?

```
function create_teacher() {
  var url = "<%= testing_teacher_path %>";

  return Ember.RSVP.Promise.cast(
    Ember.$.post(
      url,
      {
        user: {
          first_name: "John",
          last_name: "Doe"
          school: "EE3",
          email: "john@doe.com",
          password: "password"
        }
      }
    )
  );
}

module("Teacher Dashboard", {
  setup: function() {
    console.log("STARTING");
    Ember.run(HstryEd, HstryEd.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    console.log("TEARING DOWN");
    HstryEd.reset();
  }
});

asyncTest("Login", function() {
  expect(1);

  var teacher = create_teacher();
  teacher.then(function() {
    console.log("DONE");
    ok(true, "done");
    start();
  },
  function() {
    console.log("FAIL");
    ok(false, "fail");
    start();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could have to do with the Ember runloop being disabled in test mode. Have you checked out `ic-ajax`? https://github.com/instructure/ic-ajax It gives you promise-style jQuery ajax requests in a form that Ember likes, even in testing. I brought it in to solve my Ember runloop issues in testing, and have had great results so far.

Alternatively, you could try wrapping your `teacher.then(..` in an `Ember.run`.